# How to fix the issue "UWP app stopped after navigation"?

Tags: windows, mobile, uwp, windows-phone, uwp-xaml

Now I'm making an UWP app.

And I faced an issue.

When I tried to navigate to other page using `this.Frame.Navigate`, the app stopped with exit code `-1`.

Here is my code

```
private void Meetups_Pressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MeetUps));
}
```

And `MeetUps.xaml` and `MeetUps.xaml.cs` are exist.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Is it possible to show *MeetUps.xaml.cs* and *MeetUp.xaml*?

Comment: yes, there is contents in those files, and I can see it

Comment: Is it only for this one page? Maybe you have some syntax error in your xaml file you want to navigate to. Try with new, clean page.

Comment: Can you post the contents of MeetUps.xaml /xaml.cs?

Comment: @Jin So did you solve your problem? Becasue "thank you so much" doesn't tell us a lot.

Comment: yes I solved my issue